# error of finding the total line number of a large text file using the Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, cmd, findstr

I would like to find the total line number of a text file ( > 60 GB) using the Windows command prompt.

I used:

```
 findstr /R /N "^" file.txt | find /C ":"
```

But, the returned result is a negative number. Is it overflow? The file have not more than 5 billion lines. For an integer (4 Bytes),  its max range is From −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. So, I need to design a script to count the number by dividing the result with 1000 ?

If yes, please help me with how to design the Windows batch file.

Comment: you'll never need more than 640k!

Comment: @MarkFisher, Could you please clarify your meaning ? thanks

Comment: Mark Fisher is referring to the fact that MS-DOS is limited to only 640k of RAM (sort of, it's actually a bit more complicated than that). Since you're not actually using MS-DOS, a long obsolete 16-bit operating system, this isn't a problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a JScript solution.  JavaScript numbers are [always a 64-bit float data type](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp), accurate up to 15 digits as integers.  It'll take a while though.  It takes me about 15 seconds to count the lines in a 100 meg XML file with this script.

**Edit:** Since the float datatype wasn't large enough, I modified the script to use an array as a counter, then output the result as a joined string.  As long as `fso.OpenTextFile().SkipLine()` doesn't choke (for which there is no solution but to try a different language, maybe Python or Perl?), this *should* work, and hopefully it won't be too expensive a hit on performance.  I tested it on a 4.3 gig ISO file and it took about 8 minutes.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: countlines.bat
:: usage: countlines.bat filetocount.log

:: batch portion does nothing remarkable
:: but relaunches itself with jscript interpreter
@echo off

cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%~f1"

goto :EOF

:: end of batch / begin JScript */

var fso, f, file = WSH.Arguments(0), longVal = [0],
ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, b4 = new Date();

// inherits global array longVal[]
// increments each element from right to left
function inc() {
    for (var i=longVal.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (++longVal[i] == 10) {
            longVal[i] = 0;
            if (!i) {
                longVal.splice(0, 0, 0);
                i++;
            }
            continue;
        }
        else break;
    }
}

fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f = fso.OpenTextFile(file, ForReading);
while (!f.AtEndOfStream) {
    f.SkipLine();
    inc();
}
WSH.Echo(longVal.join(''));
f.Close();

var stopwatch = 'Line count completed in ' + ((new Date() - b4) / 1000.0) + 's';
WSH.StdErr.WriteLine(stopwatch);
```

Comment: would you please tell me how to run your code and do I need to install Java ? If yes, I may not be able to use it because I cannot install anything on server where the file is located.

Comment: thanks! I am not familiar with JScript, could you please tell me what is " log rotation service" ? And, what kinds of serious consideration I need ? When I run it, it may generate a large log file ?

Comment: My server does not allow to install anything. I can only copy the Jscript and run it to get the line number. Hope that this does not do anything bad in my server. Thanks !

Comment: it works. thanks! I would like to know how to get the run time of the script. I used "echo start/end time is %Time%" in the start and end of the file but I got compile error.

Comment: thanks ! it works. Could you please recommend some online resource that can help me learn the basics of Jscript ?

Comment: JScript is JavaScript, but operating in a WScript environment rather than a window. If you're comfortable with web development and know JavaScript, you already know the basics. The rest is just accessing WSH features and methods as collections and objects. Most of the time when I want to know how to do something in JScript, I just google the VBScript way of doing it (which is more common), then apply JavaScript syntax to it. Most often my Googling leads me to the [MSDN reference pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for Windows Scripting Host.

Comment: sorry to bother you, I still got negative number for a 120GB file. It was same as "findstr command" that was used in OP.

Comment: Because the file is very large and took long time to get the result. can I use "long int" in Jscript ? thanks !

Comment: @user3601704 Let's clean up all these no longer relevant comments, if you wouldn't mind to delete the ones that no longer apply to the current discussion.  Anyway, I made a modification to the script that will make the counter simulate a longint datatype.  Give this updated attempt a shot.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I am running your new code. It may take long time to get the result. When it is available, I will let you know. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bat file to count the lines. Yes, you're hitting a 32 bit int limit and the same thing would happen with set /a calculations... so some kind of division is certainly a good idea.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set Singles=0
set Thousands=0
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /nr "^" "%1"') do (
    rem echo %%a   %%b
    set /a Singles+=1
    if !Singles! equ 1000 (
        set /a Thousands+=1
        set Singles=0
    )
)
set Singles=x000%Singles%
echo %Thousands%.%Singles:~-3% thousand lines
```

I included the rem line so that you can check the output from findstr if you need to.

--- ok so the bat file solution is pretty slow ---

Here's a vbs that might be as quick as you can get (maybe even close to or better than the findstr/find times?)
To run: You can either just use: `scriptname.vbs filename` which will output the result to the screen or `cscript -nologo scriptname.vbs filename` to output at the command prompt.

Short summary of how this works. A textstream has a Line property which is a 32 bit signed int. As long as we detect each switch from + to - and - to +, we can count the total lines using the final file.Line property.

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 then
    WScript.Echo "Missing filename parameter"
    WScript.Quit
end if

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const bytesToSkip = 2000000000
Dim fso, MyFile, count, direction, position, totalSize
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Open the file to count.
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0), ForReading)

totalSize = fso.GetFile(WScript.Arguments(0)).Size
count=0
direction=1
position=0

' Jump through the file in big blocks
Do While position < totalSize
    MyFile.Skip(bytesToSkip) 'If going past of the end of the file, this doesn't error the first time
    position = position + bytesToSkip

    if MyFile.Line = 0 and direction=-1 Then
        ' Have wrapped back to 0
        count=count+1
        direction=1
    elseif direction <> abs(MyFile.Line)/MyFile.Line Then
        'Count each change from + to - or - to +
        count=count+1
        direction=direction*(-1)
    end if
    REM WScript.Echo direction & "    " & position & "    " & MyFile.Line & "    " & count
Loop

' Do final calculations
if MyFile.Line = 0 Then
    Count = Count*(2^31)
elseif direction = 1 Then
    count=Count*(2^31) + MyFile.Line
elseif direction = -1 Then
    count=Count*(2^31) + (2^31 + MyFile.Line)
end if

MyFile.Close

WScript.Echo "Total Lines = " & count
```

Comment: thanks ! But, your code cannot give correct result and also it is much slower than the findstr command in my OP. The "for loop" is a problem ? It can test it by opening a file with 100k lines. You find the  result is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could redirect the output to a temporary file and use that in the `for` loop - of course this will create a copy of the >60GB file on the HDD... This will speed things up, but I doubt you'll find any solution with a bat file or vbs that will compete with exes for speed. A vbs solution that counts (like the JScript one) takes an hour on my computer for a 3.5 billion lines. Perhaps you can tell us how long the findstr/find combination takes for your file sizes and these solutions so we have something to gauge performance on.

Comment: Try my accelerated (big skipping) VBS version and see how that goes.